# How to remove files from a list on the basis of its parent folder/directory name

Tags: java, groovy

This is my first list:

```
String[] myList = ["john","Coding","haha","tukku", "Coding/a","Coding/a/b", "folder1/file1.txt", "folder1/folder2/file1.txt"]
```

```
String[] lst1 = ["John","Coding/*", "folder1/*"]
```

```
finallist =  mylist - lst1
```

I want to remove all the files from `myList` which have their parent folder name in `lst1`
expected result

```
["haha", "tukku"]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change `lst1` to regular expression then code could be quite simple..

```
def mylist = ["john","Coding","haha","tukku", "Coding/a","Coding/a/b", 'folder1/file1.txt', 'folder1/folder2/file1.txt']

lst1 = ["john", "Coding/*", "folder1/*"]
def re = lst1.collect{ it.replaceAll('\\*', '.*') }.join('|')
// re = "john|Coding/.*|folder1/.*"
def finallist = mylist.findAll{ !(it==~re) }
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be one solution. I did not use any streams to keep the solution simple:

```java
String[] myList = {"john","Coding","haha","tukku", "Coding/a","Coding/a/b", "folder1/file1.txt", "folder1/folder2/file1.txt"};
String[] filterList = {"john","Coding/*", "folder1/*"};

ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

for(String listElement: myList) // Iterating over each list element
{
    String elementParent = listElement.split("/")[0]; // Getting the first parent (the first string before /)

    boolean toBeAdded = true; // Variable that keeps track whether this element has to be added to result or not
    for(String filterStr: filterList)
    {
        String filterParent = filterStr.split("/")[0]; // Getting the parent of the Filter String.

        if(elementParent.toLowerCase().equals(filterParent.toLowerCase())) // If The element parent and the filter parent are the same, then we do not add it.
        {
            toBeAdded = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(toBeAdded)
    {
        result.add(listElement);
    }
}

System.out.println(result);
```

And this is the output:

```
[haha, tukku]
```